# Contact form in HTML CSS but I do not create PHP code

Tags: php, html, css, contacts, contact-form

I created the contact form in html and css now comes the hard part.
Since it is my first experience with the php code sapede tell me how to create the code so that you can send the mail with all the information on the form?

Sorry for my bad English, Let me know if you didn't understand my Question

The HTML code

```
<form id="contactform">
<div class="formcolumn">
<label for="name">Nome e Cognome</label>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<label for="indirizzo">Indirizzo</label>
<input type="text" id="indirizzo" />
<ul>
<li>Consegna a Domicilio<input type="checkbox" id="domicilio" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="formcolumn">
<label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
<input type="text" id="telefono" />
<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input type="email" id="email" />
<ul>
<li>Ritiro presso la macelleria<input type="checkbox" id="macelleria" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="formcolumn_2">
<label for="consegna">Indirizzo di consegna</label>
<input type="text" id="consegna" />
<label for="note">Note</label>
<input type="text" id="note" />
<label for="feedback">Ordine</label>
<textarea id="feedback"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<input class="button" value="INVIA" type="INVIA">
</div>
</form>
```

The CSS code

```
#contactform{
    font-family:"Eras Medium ITC";
    width: 585px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.formcolumn input, #contactform textarea{
    width:95%;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    padding: 4px;
}

.formcolumn_2 input, #contactform textarea{
    width:571px;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    padding: 4px;
}

#contactform textarea{
    resize:vertical;
    height: 200px;
}

#contactform input[type="checkbox"]{
    width: auto;
    float:right;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#contactform .formcolumn{ 
    width:280px;
    float: left;
}

#contactform .formcolumn:first-of-type{
    margin-right: 25px; 
}

#contactform label { 
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    display: block;
}

#contactform ul{
    list-style:none;
    list-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}

#contactform ul li{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#contactform div.buttons{
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}

#contactform input.button{
    margin-top: 1.5EM;
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 100px;
    max-width: 600px;color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 7px;
    text-shadow: 0 -2px 1px #8a8a8a;
    background: rgb(169,3,41);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 0%, 
rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%, rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
color-stop(0%,rgba(169,3,41,1)), color-stop(44%,rgba(143,2,34,1)), 
color-stop(100%,rgba(109,0,25,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 
0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 
0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 
0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(169,3,41,1) 
0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 44%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#6d0019',GradientType=0 );
}

#contactform input.button:active{
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #8a8a8a;
    background: rgb(109,0,25);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(109,0,25,1) 0%, 
rgba(143,2,34,1) 56%, rgba(169,3,41,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
color-stop(0%,rgba(109,0,25,1)), color-stop(56%,rgba(143,2,34,1)), 
color-stop(100%,rgba(169,3,41,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(109,0,25,1) 
0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 56%,rgba(169,3,41,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(109,0,25,1) 
0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 56%,rgba(169,3,41,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(109,0,25,1) 
0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 56%,rgba(169,3,41,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(109,0,25,1) 
0%,rgba(143,2,34,1) 56%,rgba(169,3,41,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( 
startColorstr='#6d0019', endColorstr='#a90329',GradientType=0 );
}
```

Also can you tell me because even though I gave text-align: center INVIO button on the message remains on the left?

Comment: You need to add `text-align:center` to `#contactform input.button` and not to its parent - http://jsfiddle.net/5RjDt/

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this

```
<html><body> 

<form action= "post.php" method= "POST"> 

<p>Имя: </p><p> <input type= "text" name= "name"> </p> 

<p>E-mail: </p><p> <input type= "text" name= "email"></p> 

<p>Сообщение: </p><p> <textarea rows= "10" cols= "45" name= "message"></textarea></p> 

<input type= "submit" value= "Отправить"> 

</body></html>
```

where action= "post.php" php file is a connection, so you need to explicitly write this file to send letters and then connect it as in Example

Comment: Quindi devo rifare il form usando il tag <p> </p>
Inoltre come faccio poi a creare il codice php perchè è questa l'unica cosa che non so fare

Comment: So I have to redo the form using the tag </ p>
Also how do I then create the php code because this is the only thing that I can not do

Comment: this and similar form does not generate php code, so to speak form handler written separately!, php file is executed on the client side it is executed on the server side, this you need a local web server, and if you do not write cann't form handler think that expanses of the Internet can be found 100% uptime but is not guaranteed and the beam

Comment: And why do you repeat the form tag p ?

Comment: if you mean the part of the code that I sent an example of this example and use p tag does not necessarily

Answer (score 0):

```
just copy and paste..hope this will help you!

<?php
if(isset($_POST['subm']))
{

$name=$_POST['name'];   
$Indirizzo=$_POST['Indirizzo'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$consegna=$_POST['consegna'];
$note=$_POST['note'];
$feedback=$_POST['feedback'];
$to = "somebody@example.com";
$subject = "Details";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>Contact details</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Your Details</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Indirizzo</th>
<th>telefono</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>consegna</th>
<th>note</th>
<th>feedback</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>$name</td>
<td>$Indirizzo</td>
<td>$telefono</td>
<td>$email</td>
<td>$consegna</td>
<td>$note</td>
<td>$feedback</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: somebody@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: somebody@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<title>feedback form</title>
<style>

 <---your css code -->    

</style>
</head>
<body>


<form id="contactform" method="post">
<div class="formcolumn">
<label for="name">Nome e Cognome</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
<label for="indirizzo">Indirizzo</label>
<input type="text" id="indirizzo" name="Indirizzo"  />
<ul>
<li>Consegna a Domicilio<input type="checkbox" id="domicilio" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="formcolumn">
<label for="telefono">Telefono</label>
<input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" />
<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
<ul>
<li>Ritiro presso la macelleria<input type="checkbox" id="macelleria" /></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="formcolumn_2">
<label for="consegna">Indirizzo di consegna</label>
<input type="text" id="consegna" name="consegna"/>
<label for="note">Note</label>
<input type="text" id="note" name="note"/>
<label for="feedback">Ordine</label>
<textarea id="feedback" name="feedback"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<input class="button" value="INVIA" name="subm" type="submit">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```